# Connect domain different cities

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

How can i connect three server (domain controller) with a single one . These server are in different cities. And how to sync folder if i change file in one server automatically file change in other server

Comment: This question is very broad.  The short answer to your first question is probably "with a VPN" but there are lots of ways to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

Create a site-to-site VPN to connect your sites -> make sure each site is in a different subnet -> set your DCs to use each other as DNS -> set up your sites in AD -> let replication begin -> done.